Does the matrix representation of quantum gates depend on the basis?
I have read that I can chose any orthonormal basis $\{|0⟩, |1⟩\}$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$ as my basis states for a single qubit. Usually $|0⟩ = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $|1⟩ = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is chosen, but say I chose anything else. Would the matrix representation of quantum gates still be the same or would it change (e.g. or the Hadamard gate)? I searched for a while now but didn't find any answer.

Say you have state $|\psi\rangle$ and you perform a change in basis by applying $V$:
$$|\phi\rangle = V |\psi\rangle$$
Now you want to apply some unknown unitary $W$ to $|\phi\rangle$ such that it has the same effect as applying the unitary $U$ to $|\psi\rangle$.
The key to finding $W$ is to remember that if you apply the conjugate transpose of $V$ to $|\phi\rangle$, you switch back to the original basis:
$$ |\psi\rangle = V^{\dagger} |\phi\rangle .$$
So applying $U$ to $|\psi\rangle$ is equivalent to:
$$ U|\psi\rangle = U \underbrace{V^{\dagger} |\phi\rangle}_{|\psi\rangle} .$$
Lastly, you can apply $V$ to the state evolved by $U$ to change the basis again to the one you want to work in:
$$ V U|\psi\rangle = V U V^{\dagger} |\phi\rangle .$$
This means that the unitary you want to apply to the state in the new basis $|\phi\rangle$ to have the same effect as what $U$ would have in the original state $|\psi\rangle$ is:
$$ W = V U V^{\dagger} .$$
A simple example:

You start with state $|\psi\rangle = |0\rangle$ in the computational basis $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}.$
You want switch to the Hadamard basis $\{|+\rangle, |-\rangle\}$, so you apply a unitary $V$ equal to the Hadamard gate: $|\phi\rangle = H|0\rangle = |+\rangle$ (this is the equivalent to state in $|0\rangle$ in your new basis).
You want to know what gate $W$ you need to apply to $|\phi\rangle=|+\rangle$ so it has the same effect as a unitary $U$ equal to the $X$ gate on $|\psi\rangle = |0\rangle$, so you need to apply $V U V^{\dagger} = H X H$, which corresponds to a $Z$ gate.
To verify, you can see that applying a $Z$ gate to $|+\rangle$ gives you state $|-\rangle$, which if you transform back to the computational basis is state $|1\rangle$ (i.e., the state you get when you apply $X$ to $|0\rangle$).


Thank you, that is a very good explanation!

Yes, the matrix representation changes. For example, the Pauli $X$ gate in the standard basis is
$$
X\equiv \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which you evaluate by taking your orthonormal basis, in this case $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ and evaluating terms $\langle a|X|b\rangle$ where distinct $a$ map to rows, and distinct $b$ map to columns.
If I pick another basis, perhaps the $|\pm\rangle=(|0\rangle\pm|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ basis. Now the top-left element, for example, is $\langle +|X|+\rangle=1$. So, now you end up with a representation
$$
X\equiv\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Very different.

More details on the procedure of representation... Pick an orthonormal basis $\{|u_i\rangle\}$. A unitary operator $U$ has a representation in that basis of a matrix $M$ with matrix elements
$$
M_{ij}=\langle u_i|U|u_j\rangle.
$$
After all, what this is essentially saying is that
$$
U=\sum_{i,j}M_{ij}|u_i\rangle\langle u_j|,
$$
which is straightforward to prove.
So, going back to the example of an $X$ operator, which we know has the effect of flipping vectors of the standard basis: $X|0\rangle=|1\rangle$ and $X|1\rangle=|0\rangle$. (You should basically take this as the definition of your operator, and forget about the matrix you're possibly used to thinking about.) As a result of these definition, and linearity, we know that $X|+\rangle=|+\rangle$ and $X|-\rangle=-|-\rangle$. So now you just work through all 4 matrix elements and find the claimed representation in the $|\pm\rangle$ basis.

Thank you for your answer! But I don't really understand what you mean by "evaluating terms $⟨a|X|b⟩$ where distinct a map to rows, and distinct b map to columns". Can you explain in more detail what you mean with that? And why that would result in the X gate?

Some other very good answers have been posted, and this answer is not really useful on it's own, but I think it adds something in conjunction with the others. Really, quantum gates should be thought of as order-2 tensors acting on the Hilbert space. Once a basis is fixed, this just means quantum gates are matrices acting on the Hilbert space, but when we change basis by a transformation $L_{ij}$, the state vectors change by $v'_i=L_{ij}v_j$ and the quantum gates $T$ transform like $T_{ij}' = L_{ip}L_{jq} T_{pq} = (LTL^T)_{ij}$. This is a particularly nice way of thinking about things.
I do not know of any examples of order-3 tensors coming up in quantum mechanics, but it's an interesting thought, I'd be curious if anyone had any examples.
